# get submit form action with array

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, forms

i have a form based on database mysql ,just like this

```
<form name="" id="form1" method="GET" action="submit.php"></form> 
<?php 
include 'connection.php';
$myquery="SELECT * FROM `tbl` " ;
$params=mysql_query($myquery) or die (mysql_error()); 
while ($param=mysql_fetch_assoc($params))
{?> 

   <input name="<?php echo $param['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $param['child_id'] ?>" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox<?php echo $param['id'] ?>" value="Yes" form="form1" />  
   <input class="form-control text-center" form="form1" name="desc<?php echo $param['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $param['desc'] ?>"/>
   <input class="form-control text-center" form="form1" name="value <?php echo $param['id'] ?>" value="<?php echo $param['value'] ?>"/>
   <select class="form-control" form="form1" id="" name="select<?php echo $param['id'] ?>">          
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="OK">OK</option>
      <option value="NOK">NOK</option>
   </select>
<?php } ?>
 <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-success btn-s-md btn-rounded" form="form1"><i class="icon-save"></i>Save</button>
```

how can i submit (do update )  to mysql database with this form , i am a newbie in php .
thanks

Comment: Why you keep form in loop? you want to many forms? then add a submit button in loop with unique name and and get submit data

Comment: Firstly remove form from the loop if you don't want to have many forms. Also, without submit button how can you submit your form

Comment: sorry i made a mistake , now i have all ready edited my code , but still have no idea to submit the action thanks

Comment: add submit button before </form> tag and better to use POST instead of GET in your form method

Comment: Use mysqli_* functions for writing scripts. mysql_* functions going to deprecated. There is a good tutorial here http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Comment: great thanks to @fortune and all everyone, i learn a lot from all of you guys,

Answer (score 1):

So yes you have to add the balise form at this end. Then I advice you to add a hidden value with your id.

```
<input type="hidden" name"id" value="<?php echo  $param['id'] ; ?>">
```

After ad in your page submit.php,

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
if (isset($_POST["id"])){ 
$id=$_POST["id"];#so you can recover your id
$myquery="UPDATE ... " ;
mysql_query($myquery) or die (mysql_error());
echo "update success";# you can add whatever you want here 
}?>
```

Comment: great thanks to all of you for answer my question, i learn it a lot from all of you guys,since i was learn it by myself and i was not college

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you understand my explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap all your form elements into the `<form>` tag. So place your closing tag (`</form>`) at the end of your form.

```
<form name="" id="form1" method="GET" action="submit.php">
    <input name="..." />
    <select>          
        <option value="...">...</option>
        ...
    </select>
    <button>...</button>
</form>
```

By the way: [PHP's `mysql`-functions are deprecated. Use `mysqli` instead!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)